# Building pandas for pypy

Tags: python, pandas, pypy

I fail to compile pandas (0.17.0) for pypy 4.0.0 on osx and raspbian.

It fails in both cases, however for different reasons:

raspbian:

```
pandas/lib.c:84937:76: error: ‘PyDateTime_Date’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    pandas/lib.c:84938:84: error: ‘PyDateTime_DateTime’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

osx:

```
In file included from pandas/src/datetime_helper.h:3:
    /Users/sonium/Raspbrewry/venv-pypy/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayscalars.h:8:3: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct PyBoolScalarObject' vs 'struct PyBoolScalarObject')
    } PyBoolScalarObject;
```

i know that pandas does not officially support pypy, but shouldn't pypy be a drop-in replacement?

Comment: pypy barely supports numpy, this is not likely to happen in the foreseeable future; any library that has compiled code is also not likely to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas as of now is not supported under PyPy. We're trying to improve the situation, but as of pypy 4.0 you can't use pandas directly under pypy (but you can try some solution like pymetabiosis)

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at pymetabiosis. I mainly want to use bokeh (and bokeh-server) which has pandas as a dependency. Can this be done with pymetabiosis without code changes in bokeh?

Comment: bokeh I believe works with pypy (although I've never tried it myself)

Comment: bokeh depends on pandas, that's the problem